# How to get pandas to roll through entire series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-rolling

## Pandas Rolling function

### Last elements when window_size == step_size

I can't seem to get the last three element of an example 9 element series to be rolled on, when my window size and step size are both 3.

Is the below an intended behaviour of `pandas`?

#### My desired outcome

If so how can I roll over the `Series` so that:

`pd.Series([1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3.]).rolling(window=3, step=3).mean()`

evaluate to `pd.Series([1., 2., 3.,])`?

#### Example

```py
    import pandas as pd

    def print_mean(x):
        print(x)
        return x.mean()

    df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0]})

    df["left"] = (
        df["A"].rolling(window=3, step=3, closed="left").apply(print_mean, raw=False)
    )
    df["right"] = (
        df["A"].rolling(window=3, step=3, closed="right").apply(print_mean, raw=False)
    )
    df["both"] = (
        df["A"].rolling(window=3, step=3, closed="both").apply(print_mean, raw=False)
    )
    df["neither"] = (
        df["A"].rolling(window=3, step=3, closed="neither").apply(print_mean, raw=False)
    )
```

This evaluates to:

```
     A  left  right  both  neither
0  0.0   NaN    NaN   NaN      NaN
1  1.0   NaN    NaN   NaN      NaN
2  2.0   NaN    NaN   NaN      NaN
3  3.0   1.0    2.0   1.5      NaN
4  4.0   NaN    NaN   NaN      NaN
5  5.0   NaN    NaN   NaN      NaN
6  6.0   4.0    5.0   4.5      NaN
7  7.0   NaN    NaN   NaN      NaN
8  8.0   NaN    NaN   NaN      NaN
```

and prints:

```
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
dtype: float64
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
dtype: float64
```

```
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
dtype: float64
4    4.0
5    5.0
6    6.0
dtype: float64
```

```
0    0.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
dtype: float64
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    5.0
6    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use step here, which "evaluate[s] the window at every step result, equivalent to slicing as [::step]?"

Comment: Yes, I would like to do convolution on these series.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what `step` is doing? -- try the following to see if this is still what you are looking for and play around with different steps, windows, min_periods, etc.: `for win in pd.Series([1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3.]).rolling(window=3, step=3): print(win)`

Comment: Yes, step configures how far the start of the next window's left index is compared to the previous one.

Comment: What I don't understand is, for eg.: in your example it outputs: 
```
0    1.0
dtype: float64
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    2.0
dtype: float64
4    2.0
5    2.0
6    3.0
dtype: float64
```
Why does it handle the first element like that?

Comment: Because you have the step set to three so it is the equivalent of doing `s[::3]` (where `s` is the series). Notice the index - `[0, 3, 6]` You cannot look back 2 more steps from the first element in the array so it returns nan. Then the next index (3) you look back two more spots (index 1,2,3) and take the mean, which is (1+1+2)/3 and equals 1.33

Comment: I am not sure if I got the question correctly but is it possible you are looking for something like this? `ser.groupby(ser.index // 3).mean()` (where `ser = pd.Series([1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3.])`).

Comment: @user19308385 I think you are correct. Post it as an answer, you'll get +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks @It_is_Chris I understand now. Thanks user19308385 this is a working method in the example above. (However I'll have to adopt it to datetime.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try subsetting every 3 rows by using the `%` operator:

```py
df[df.index % 3 == 0]
```

This will output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but how would you aggregate the values inbetween?